# Can't add an attribute to an element using $postLink - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I have a simple component and what I'm trying to do is to add to my input element an attribute `multiple` dynamically but somewhy it doesn't work. Why? And is there any way to do what I want?

```
app.component('myComponent', {
    templateUrl: 'tmpl.html',
    bindings: {
        str: '@'
    },
    controller: function () {
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.$postLink = function () {
            $('#myInputId').attr('multiple', '');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @lenilsondc yeah, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
app.component('myComponent', {
    templateUrl: 'tmpl.html',
    bindings: {
        str: '@'
    },
    controller: function ($element) {
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.$postLink = function () {
            $element.find('input').attr('multiple', 'multiple');
        }
    }
}
```

The trick was in linking stuff. Code from the question doesn't work because the `input` not exists in DOM yet at the time `$postLink` hook triggered. So what we need is to inject `$element` service into controller and use it to manipulate DOM.